# Error inflating anything from the design support library

Tags: android, xml, gradle, build.gradle

I am trying to implement floating labels in edit text which requires **com.android.support:design: 23.0.1** but the design support library is not getting compiled.

Here is my build.gradle for app and project. Please point out mistakes or give suggestions.

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.searchable"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
}
```

**PROJECT build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
```

**ERROR**

> Error:(24, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:design:22.2.0

I also tried downloading the jar file and including it as a library. 
The compilation in this case does not pose any problem but the XML file returns the following error during build.

**XMl**

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout

    android:id="@+id/input_layout_password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input_password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="password" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

**ERROR**

> The following class cannot be instantiated
>        -android.support.design.TextInputLayout(Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)

When I click on Open Class link the jar decompiler shows the class source code, so I am assuming that thee is no problem in including the library.

**EDIT**

I found out that there is a ***problem in including any dependency*** in Gradle and it returns the same compilation error ***irrespective of the library included***.

Comment: Can u open standalone SDK Manager and check  android support repository is installed or not. Which is under "Extras"?

Comment: open standalone SDK Manager and install buildToolsVersion "22.2.0"    clean and rebuild your project...

Answer (score 1):

Change your compileSdkVersion to 23 and add this to app level build.gradle file
`compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'`

Comment: Same as described in the post.

Comment: change your buildToolsVersion to 23.0.3 and compileSdkVersion to 23

Comment: Please refer the edit and give suggestions if possible.

Comment: try adding this `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'` and make sure that you have installed Android support library from SDK manager. Refer this link [Setup support library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html)

Answer (score 0):

May be it will help you as I tried in this case..
Put in Gradle dependencies.

```
        dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'  
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
  }
```

And that you have intialized like this

```
TextInputLayout Password;
Password= (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.input_password);
```

Thanks..

Comment: I didn't even reach the initialization stage. the xml file itself gives an error